# Would it be possible to auto-link existing company pages in careers 2.0 profile work history?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Fairly straightforward request: If I say I work (or have worked) at "Company X Inc" and The company page "careers.stackoverflow.com/company/company-x-inc" exists, it would be *great* if my work history would just link to their page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, although I can see your point-of-view, there is a strong reason to *not* do so.

From a security standpoint, you don't want to associate with unknown third-parties. You might even accidentally link, saying www.mircosoft.com and that's some malicious site.

Another thing is that your profile is really just a marketing piece. They are only trying to see if you're worthy of a follow-up connection, be it in-person interview or phone call. Even if you were linking to sites, they just really wouldn't be clicking.

EDIT: OOPS, misunderstanding...

Well, you're just linking within Profiles. Well, that seems reasonable then. Though I'm not sure it adds much to the equation of getting a job. The playing field will still be even for all candidates

Comment: I am a bit of a meta-data/"markup all the things" nut. In this case, my company has posted a job offering recently and decided to invite all of us SO users to their new company page to make it look more inviting. This links the company page to my SO profile, but doesn't link my careers profile to the company explicitly, it is still just dumb text rather than hypertext, which is what the internet is all about. Just seems like a waste not to invert the relationship since the data is there.